# Google calendar automatically unchecks Reminders

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

I've been using Google Calendar for a long time and organizing events, reminders and tasks. But Its reminder items occasionally disappears and I have to manually check the Reminder box on the left panel to show them on top. Does anyone know why the Reminder box automatically unchecks itself?

[image]

Comment: are they not carrying over to the next day? If you created reminders that you didn't mark as done in Inbox, the Google app, or Keep, you'll see them in the "All day" section of your calendar.

Comment: yes I want them to be all day to be shown on the top panel. But the issue is I have to occasionally manually check that Reminders box.